# Load remote image without extension

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to load remote images without filename extensions. The URLs looks something like this:

```
http://i.efritin-st.com/73b7a349-9c58-4881-886f-39e7c4cf7c2c/88/66/cropped.webp
```

And my code looks like:

```
<Image
  source={{uri: imageUri}}
  style={{width: 60, height: 88}}
/>;
```

Where the `imageUri` is the full URL listed above. It works well for other images like e.g. `http://i.imgur.com/UePbdph.jpg`. But not when I point at something without a regular extension.

Or at least thats my guess. Any other ideas? Not proper headers or something for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example URL actually has an extension ".webp". It's a [WebP](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/) image. iOS does not support WebP out of the box and react-native does not add any support either. If you are in control of the image cropping, the easiest solution would be to change the format to JPEG (or any other [supported format](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/ImageIOGuide/imageio_basics/ikpg_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005462-CH216-DontLinkElementID_3)).

Alternatively you can register your own RCTImageDataDecoder implementation for WebP. This shouldn't be too hard. You can have a look at the implementation of RCTGIFImageDecoder to see how it is done. For creating the UIImage you could use [iOS-WebP](http://seanooi.github.io/iOS-WebP/) for example.